# Access bfile from other oracle database

Tags: oracle

I have two Oracle databases using Oracle Standard Edition Two 12.1, DB1 and DB2.
DB1 contains the following table a FILE_TABLE:

```
ColumnName  DataType
File_Id     Number
File_Ref    Bfile
```

I am storing Bfile into File_Ref of a FILE_TABLE table.
I want to access the Bfile from FILE_TABLE table and show it in DB2.

I have tried it using the database link. Using database link, I tried to do so:

```
SELECT  FILE_REF FROM FILE_TABLE@dblink;
```

but it's giving an error: ORA-22992: cannot use LOB locators selected from remote tables

I also tried the DBMS_FILE_TRANSFER but when I researched on it, I got to know that we can only transfer System data files but not Bfile.
Is it true?
This is the syntax I used to transfer file:

```
DBMS_FILE_TRANSFER.put_file(
source_directory_object => 'db1_dir',
source_file_name => 'db1test.html',
destination_directory_object => 'db2_dir',
destination_file_name => 'db2test.html');
destination_database => 'db1_to_db2',
END;
/
```

But I was getting an error:

> ORA-19505: failed to identify file "/db1_dir/db1test.html"
>
> ORA-27046: file size is not a multiple of logical block size
>
> Additional information: 1
>
> ORA-02063: preceding 3 lines from db1_to_db2
>
> ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_FILE_TRANSFER", line 37
>
> ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_FILE_TRANSFER", line 132
>
> ORA-06512: at line 2
>
> 19505. 00000 -  "failed to identify file \"%s\""
>
> *Cause:    call to identify the file returned an error
>
> *Action:   check additional messages, and check if the file exists

Is there any way to do it using database link? Are there any other solutions to move a Bfile from one Database to other?

Comment: Table- and column names in your example sql don't match the desciption of your table. Please provide a correct description of your table. What is bfile_col_nm for example?

Comment: Sorry, I was just giving an example. I have corrected the SQL query.

Comment: I can't test right now but can you `insert` into a table instead of `select`ing?

Comment: Is this a one time copy or an on-going requirement?

Comment: Did you try data pump? Export from DB1 and import into DB2?

Comment: @BobC - it is ongoing requirement

Comment: @Littlefoot - I am not looking for copying. I want to access the object from another database.

Answer (score 1):

The ora-27046 is generally a sign that during the file transfer the file has been changed. This can be caused by firewalls. Have you verified with that the file is the same.

In addition when you get ora-27046 its not the only error, you get an error stack of several errors. It would be good to post the complete error stack. Also you don't mention which oracle release you are using.

Comment: Added error stack. Also, added Oracle version. I'm using Oracle Standard Edition Two.

Comment: any firewalls/NAT's or similar devices between the two databases?

Comment: Both the databases are on AWS RDS Oracle. I don't think there is a firewall issue.

Comment: @Dang I didn't think AWS even allowed access to the filesystem?  You might want to add details about how you're accessing those files to the question.  Also, it's not quite clear what exactly you want to do.  The question talks about "moving" bfiles, but your comment says you're "not looking for copying".  A simple database link won't work for reading.  Even the writing-instead-of-reading trick doesn't work for BFILEs.  And the [LOB APIs](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADLOB/adlob_bfile_ops.htm#ADLOB012) won't help much either: "LOB APIs do not support loading data into BFILEs."